# How could I change the color of option tag when it is hover(CSS)?

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to make a different `<select>` tag and I have trouble with the `<option>` tag.

When I hover over the `<option>` tag, the background does not work.

The code:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
select > option{
  background:red;
}
```

I tried this code but not working:

```
option:hover {
  background:red;
}
option:checked {
  background:red;
}
```

I wonder that if I can set the background color of the `<option>` tags when I hover over them. I **only want CSS solutions** and I do not want ANY JavaScript solutions.

Comment: Try to put a div inside <option>, Get hold of that div and give it background color

Comment: The code you tried is okay. the select element should have a size attribute greater than 1. The default is 1. so add attribute size to your select, for example <select size = "2"> and try again

Comment: @YusufOyebanji I tried that but it is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could change the color of option tag when it is hover in CSS. The below code is an example with a red background and white text color. This code will change the background (red) and text color (white) of the hovered option in the select element when the select element is also being hovered over.

```
    select:hover option:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```
    <select size = "3">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

the select element should have a size attribute greater than 1. The default is 1. so add attribute size to your select, for example

Additionally, some browsers may only allow limited styling of the option element, such as the font color and background color

[image]